# Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException',

Tags: iphone, ios, sdk

i hav this error. can anyone help me...

```
Call stack at first throw:
(
    0   CoreFoundation                      0x00dc25a9 __exceptionPreprocess + 185
    1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x00f16313 objc_exception_throw + 44
    2   CoreFoundation                      0x00dc40bb -[NSObject(NSObject) doesNotRecognizeSelector:] + 187
    3   CoreFoundation                      0x00d33966 ___forwarding___ + 966
    4   CoreFoundation                      0x00d33522 _CF_forwarding_prep_0 + 50
    5   UIKit                               0x002b24fd -[UIApplication sendAction:to:from:forEvent:] + 119
    6   UIKit                               0x00342799 -[UIControl sendAction:to:forEvent:] + 67
    7   UIKit                               0x00344c2b -[UIControl(Internal) _sendActionsForEvents:withEvent:] + 527
    8   UIKit                               0x003437d8 -[UIControl touchesEnded:withEvent:] + 458
    9   UIKit                               0x002d6ded -[UIWindow _sendTouchesForEvent:] + 567
    10  UIKit                               0x002b7c37 -[UIApplication sendEvent:] + 447
    11  UIKit                               0x002bcf2e _UIApplicationHandleEvent + 7576
    12  GraphicsServices                    0x0171a992 PurpleEventCallback + 1550
    13  CoreFoundation                      0x00da3944 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_SOURCE1_PERFORM_FUNCTION__ + 52
    14  CoreFoundation                      0x00d03cf7 __CFRunLoopDoSource1 + 215
    15  CoreFoundation                      0x00d00f83 __CFRunLoopRun + 979
    16  CoreFoundation                      0x00d00840 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 208
    17  CoreFoundation                      0x00d00761 CFRunLoopRunInMode + 97
    18  GraphicsServices                    0x017191c4 GSEventRunModal + 217
    19  GraphicsServices                    0x01719289 GSEventRun + 115
    20  UIKit                               0x002c0c93 UIApplicationMain + 1160
    21  BasicNavigation                     0x00001ea0 main + 102
    22  BasicNavigation                     0x00001e31 start + 53
)
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'NSException'
Program received signal:  “SIGABRT”.
(gdb)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**When you are getting this error?**

> [NSInvalidArgumentException](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Miscellaneous/Foundation_Constants/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/c_ref/NSInvalidArgumentException)
>
> Name of an exception that occurs when you pass an invalid argument
>   to a method, such as a nil pointer where a non-nil object is required.

Answer (score 1):

```
-[NSObject(NSObject) doesNotRecognizeSelector:]
```

indicates that one of your objects does not recognize the selector method. You are probably calling a method using an object which does not perform the particular method. Please post your code so that you can get the exact reason.